# View shows a blank page with no error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

currently learning CodeIgniter using version 3.0,PHP 5.5, MySQL on WAMP and Sublime Text 3 as my editor. I'm attempting to load a view but the page is blank with no error even though error_reporting is turned on. When I echo my array, it displays the data. Below are my table and code

[image: Mysql database products table]

Below are the code for my model, control and view in that order

MODEL (product.php)

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Product extends CI_Model {

function get_products() {
    $this->db->select()->from('products')->order_by('name','desc');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}

}
```

CONTROLLER (products.php)

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Products extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('product');
    $data['products']=$this->product->get_products();
    $this->load->view('pro_index', $data, TRUE);
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($data['products']); "</pre>";
}

}
```

VIEW (pro_index.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Title Page</title>

</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        if (isset($products)) {
            foreach ($products as $row) {
            echo "<div>"."<h2>".$row["name"]."</h2>"."</div>"; 
            echo "what is this?";
            } 
        } 
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

What could i possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried print_r($products); in view?

Comment: Just did that now and the result is still the same

Comment: Try to open your different PHP files separately to see if they generate fatal errors.

Comment: try to echo print_r($data['products']); in your controller

Comment: make sure that model produces right data

Comment: Try with this `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);`

Comment: @f_anto that works fine. Looking at the code you will see I commented that line out in the controller

Comment: @JuliePelletier only the controller file opens, the others show 404 page not found. I believe this is how codeigniter works

Comment: okee I see, now, make sure that you place the view file in right place/right folder

Comment: @Rishi this is my current configuration error_reporting = E_ALL and display_errors = On

Comment: @f_anto it is in the view folder as should be

Comment: Try with the below changes,    in Model query should return like :  return $query;

In a controller : $data['products']=$this->product->get_products();

and in a View  if (isset($products)) {
            foreach ($products->result() as $row) {
            echo "<div>"."<h2>".$row["name"]."</h2>"."</div>"; 
            echo "what is this?";
            } 
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Controller, try removing the third parameter (TRUE).

> This is used for returning data (such as JSON, etc.)

```
    //this->load->view('pro_index', $data, TRUE);
    this->load->view('pro_index', $data);
```

Comment: Thanks! Removing TRUE fixed it. Wow!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public function index()
{
$this->load->model('product');
$this->data['products']=$this->product->get_products();
$this->load->view('pro_index', $this->data, TRUE);
}
```

Comment: Got a fatal error: Cannot access empty property on $this->data ['products']=$this->product->get_products ();

Comment: i thinking function call is wrong $this->product->get_products(); to $this->get_products();

Comment: Doing that returns fatal error: Call to undefined method::get_products () on the same line

Comment: rename model to Product_model

Comment: rename model to Product_model load model as $this->load->model('Product_model'); change this line $this->product->get_products(); to $this->Product_model->get_products();

Answer (score 0):

You were returning the array data with "$data" to your view page and you are looping with "foreach ($products as $row)". You have to change the foreach loop $products to $data.

In model

$this->load->view('pro_index', $data, TRUE);

In view page

foreach ($products as $row)